# Using digicamcontrol to control Nikon camera using Python?

Tags: python, camera, usb

Has anyone been successful in doing this on windows? I'm trying to command a DSLR camera to take photos with Python over USB on a Windows machine. Or do you have a better solution (I am unable to switch to Linux).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working solution, using Python 3.5 (installed via Anaconda), BTW.

The parameters for the ISO and shutter are hardwired, but this should get you going if you ever need it.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import datetime 

def func_TakeNikonPicture(input_filename):
    camera_command = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\digiCamControl\CameraControlCmd.exe'
    camera_command_details = '/filename ./' + input_filename + ' /capture /iso 500 /shutter 1/30 /aperture 1.8'
    print('camera details = ',camera_command_details)
    full_command=camera_command + ' ' + camera_command_details
    p = subprocess.Popen(full_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()  

    #This makes the wait possible
    p_status = p.wait(1)
    # print(p.stdout.readline())

    #This will give you the output of the command being executed
    print('Command output: ' + str(output))
    print('Command err: ' + str(err))

    print('done')


if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
    rawimagename = 'test.jpg'
else:   
    # sys.argv[0] is the program name, sys.argv[1] is the first file, etc.
    # need to shift this over
    files = sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)]
    # Read the image
    rawimagename = files[0]
    if(os.path.isfile(rawimagename) is True):
        print("File exists...not overwriting.")
        sys.exit()

# Store date/time for file uniqueness
current_dt=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
print("Current date time = " + current_dt)
rawimagename=current_dt + '_' + rawimagename

print('Name of raw image will be: ', rawimagename)

# take picture
func_TakeNikonPicture(rawimagename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Digicamcontrol have a remote utility which can control the application almost all aspects, the utility can be run in command prompt or execute using subprocess.call in Python

For more info about utility command line arguments check this link http://digicamcontrol.com/doc/userguide/remoteutil